# Uninstall QGIS from Mac

Tags: qgis, mac

I'm working on QGIS 2.18.13 version on my Mac. Now I want to change to 2.18.15 version. On Windows, it's really easy to make.

After uninstalling from the control panel, you go through the .qgis2 to remove it and it's completely gone. However, on Mac, I can't find this folder.

Could you please describe to me the method to follow to uninstall it?

Comment: How do you install QGIS on your Mac OS X? For example [NextGIS Installer](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) has uninstall option available from Launchpad. Also nice autoupdate option from QGIS exists. Currently 2.14 only available. 2.18 coming soon.